# jquery ajax load specific div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got one issue I haven't been able to figure out I've tried a couple different things to attempt to alleviate the problem that I found on stackoverflow, but they are not working for me.

This is my ajax code right now

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/getreviews.php',
        data: {},
           success: function(data) {
               alert(data);
               $('#renow').val( $(data).find('#now').val() );
               $('#rehour').val( $(data).find('#hour').val() );
               $('#reday').val( $(data).find('#day').val() );
           }
    });
```

the getreviews.php page has 3 divs that it returns.. I would just load all three but they are in seperate parts of the page so I'm needing to load a single div from the return to a specific div's

I have also tried these ways

```
$('#renow').val( $(data).html().find('#now').val() );
$('#renow').html( $(data).find('#now').val() );
```

I do get the divs printed in the alert so I know it's returning correctly...

UPDATE:
If I use $('#renow').html( $(data).html() );  I get the first div element inserted

Comment: what does `data` contains?

Comment: <div id="now">8</div>

<div id="hour">0</div>

<div id="day">0</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `find` to `filter` (to query within a dynamically created element) and `val` to `html` here: `$('#renow').val( $(data).find('#now').val() );`:

```
           $('#renow').html( $(data).filter('#now').html() );
           $('#rehour').html( $(data).filter('#hour').html() );
           $('#reday').html( $(data).filter('#day').html() );
```

if you want to get whole div with html try this:

```
           $('#renow').html( $(data).filter('#now').get(0).outerHTML );
           $('#rehour').html( $(data).filter('#hour').get(0).outerHTML );
           $('#reday').html( $(data).filter('#day').get(0).outerHTML );
```

Comment: @chris3spice hm, should work.. according to html that you posted in comment

Comment: That did it! Thank you, I was starting to mess around with more .find and others so you saved me a lot of headache with trial and error!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned, data contains `<div>8</div>`

```
$(data).find('#now').val()  // will not work
```

You can't use `val()` for `div` elements, instead use `.text()`

```
$(data).find('#now').text()
```

---

### Updates:

Based on the new data value

```
<div id="now">8</div> <div id="hour">0</div> <div id="day">0</div>
```

Try my below code

```
$('#renow').html( $($(data)[0]).text() ) );
$('#rehour').html( $($(data)[1]).text() ) );
$('#reday').html( $($(data)[2]).text() ) );
```

**Reason:** I suspect that the `data` is holding the html elements in `string` data type something like

```
data = '<div id="now">8</div> <div id="hour">0</div> <div id="day">0</div>';
```

Comment: @chris3spice can you share the what is the dataType of `data`. Then what does `#renow, #rehour, #reday` elements are?

Comment: @chris3spice press f12 and check console for errors?

Comment: No errors are seen and it should return be returning a plain object or string after looking it up

Comment: @chris3spice hen what does `#renow, #rehour, #reday` elements are?

Comment: They are div elements <div class="renow" id="renow"></div>

Answer (score 0):

If the `divs` marked with i.e. `#renow` are `<div>` tags and not inputs use html() instead of val()

```
$('#renow').html( $(data).find('#now').html() );
```

Comment: console log your `data` and post this over here.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `.val` after the `.find()` to `.html()`.

Otherwise, from the initial comments, data is containing HTML, but is being treated like a string. You'll need to parse the string into HTML nodes first. This can be done with `var nodes = $.parseHTML(data)`

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

EDIT:

Would make your code like this:

```
success = function(data) {
           var nodes = $.parseHTML("<div>"+data+"</div>");

           $('#renow').html( $(nodes).find('#now').html() );
           $('#rehour').html( $(nodes).find('#hour').html() );
           $('#reday').html( $(nodes).find('#day').html() );
       }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLmPV/

The problem was that your HTML isn't wrapped in anything, you can only use `.find()` on a parent node, of which there is none. Thus the `"<div>"+data+"</div>"` is necessary.

It should also be mentioned that this is a really bad way of passing data from PHP to the client.. you should use JSON. (I made this mistake too when I was just getting started)

Comment: Not sure how the whole nodes thing worked...I tried

var nodes = $.parseHTML(data); then put "nodes" in where I had data, and it wouldn't work, not sure that is correct though.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to play around with it now!